# Make link clickable, but also have the dropdown?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have an navigation bar, where I have an "nav-item" with a dropdown function.

But what I want is the "button / nav-item", that is visible in the navb-bar to be clickable and have a redirect to another page, and then the dropdown arrow should be on the right side, where you can click on the arrow and then get the dropdown menu.

I have two approaches:

**1.**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Navbar Toggle -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <!-- Navbar Toggle END -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <!-- Navbar Items Links-->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <!-- Home -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="../Startseite/Index.jsp">Home <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
      </li>
      <!-- Gruppen Dropdown-->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#gruppen" id="navbardrop1" data-toggle="dropdown">Gruppen <i class="fas fa-users"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#gruppe1">Gruppe 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#gruppe2">Gruppe 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#gruppe3">Gruppe 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Zahlungen -->
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="../Zahlungsuebersicht/Zahlungsuebersicht.jsp">Zahlungen
                <i class="fas fa-receipt"></i>
            </a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Navbar Items Rechts-->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Profil -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#asd" id="navbardrop2" data-toggle="dropdown">Benutzer <i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#asd">Profil bearbeiten <i
                            class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
                    </a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#asd">Abmelden <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="../Registrieren/Registrieren.jsp">Registrieren <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Navbar Items END -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

This one is from the design what I am looking for, but I would like the  element "Gruppen" clickable, so it redirects you to another page.

**2**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Navbar Toggle -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <!-- Navbar Toggle END -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <!-- Navbar Items Links-->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <!-- Home -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="../Startseite/Index.jsp">Home <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
      </li>
      <!-- Gruppen Dropdown-->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#gruppen">Gruppen <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop1" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#gruppe1">Gruppe 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#gruppe2">Gruppe 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#gruppe3">Gruppe 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Zahlungen -->
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="../Zahlungsuebersicht/Zahlungsuebersicht.jsp">Zahlungen
                <i class="fas fa-receipt"></i>
            </a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Navbar Items Rechts-->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Profil -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#asd" id="navbardrop2" data-toggle="dropdown">Benutzer <i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#asd">Profil bearbeiten <i
                            class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
                    </a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#asd">Abmelden <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- /c:if -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="../Registrieren/Registrieren.jsp">Registrieren <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Navbar Items END -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

This one solution is really dirty in my opinion.

Isn't there a clean way to achieve a proper solution?
I'm pretty new to all HTML, Bootstrap and CSS.

**EDIT:** I have no idea why, but i have run the two exact same code snippets on my local server, and the outcome was different... I want it to like the second approach, but without the arrow being a navitem by it's own, but when I do it, the dropdown arrow is at the top of the navbar, like above all the text. is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I made 2 snippets. I am not sure they look like you want.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you! I'll edit them to have the look I have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your current code structure simplified:**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop1" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Gruppen <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
  </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </div>
</li>
```

As I understood - the aim is to make `<i class="fas fa-users"></i>` a separate dropdown link and the style should not degrade.

**This will solve your issue:**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown nav-link">
  <a href="/#yourlink">
  Gruppen 
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop1" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
  </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </div>
</li>
```

The trick is in the `nav-link` class, which makes the propper positioning of your menu element. Moving it to the `<li>` element may have caused some conflicts in styles if the CSS was more complex, so be careful with moving class from one element to another in future.

**Note**: you must understand that the dropdown menu should not be made the way you want them now, because interacting with it the average user expects a dropdown after the click, not the redirect to some external page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How would you recommend this to be solved in a way that the average user understands / expects this to function?

Comment: I'd try splitting them visually, there is also a special documentation section here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#split-button-dropdowns